# How do I move a request to API in laravel?

Tags: laravel, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, redirect

I can't seem to find an answer on the web or maybe I'm missing something.

Let's say my laravel application domain is `my-laravel.com`

Now I want to make requests at `api.my-laravel.com` which will work just same as `my-laravel.com/api/`

How do I do that?

Solution: Changed `prefix('api')` to `domain('api.my-laravel.com')` in `RouteServiceProvider@mapApiRoutes`

Comment: Just simply point your api.domian to domain.com/api/ ...simply update DNS ....also look at 
https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/7366
and https://github.com/hamedb89/enhanced-router

Comment: Check your `RouteServiceProvider` then remove the `api` prefix in `mapApiRoutes` method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may group your routes in a sub-domain, change your `routes/api.php`

```
Route::group(["domain" => "api.domain.key"], function() {
     // your api routes.
});
```

Edit:
Check your `RouteServiceProvider` then remove the `api` prefix in `mapApiRoutes` method.

Comment: It still requires me to use `api.domain.key/api/`

Comment: Check your `RouteServiceProvider` then remove the `api` prefix in `mapApiRoutes` method.

Comment: Ah that was easy. Changed prefix('api') to domain('my-api-domain') and it's all fine now. Thanks. Can you post this answer as a parent comment so I can accept it?

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively(Except DNS and mod_rewrite)

**Sub-Domain Routing**

Route groups may also be used to handle sub-domain routing. Sub-domains may be assigned route parameters just like route URIs, allowing you to capture a portion of the sub-domain for usage in your route or controller. The sub-domain may be specified by calling the the domain method before defining the group:

```
Route::domain('{account}.myapp.com')->group(function () {
    Route::get('user/{id}', function ($account, $id) {
        //
    });
});
```

Source: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/routing#route-group-sub-domain-routing

**Note:**
Before this map your subdomain to point your server and point your domain (laravel.com)

Comment: Do I get to do this in `routes/web.php` for api routes? My routes are in `routes/api.php`. I'm trying to use `api.domain.com` instead of `domain.com/api/`.

Comment: same way in api.php , does not matter because both api.php and web.php are same the difference is only the route middleware and groups. So in short content of api.php routes and web.php are same in the sense.

Comment: It didn't help much. Ran into a lot of errors about cookies and session data cause API does not use them.